# What type of resistor component is this?

Tags: resistors, radio, inductive, vacuum-tube

I have an RCA Victor 35x tube radio and I need to know what type of resistor this is and what it's purpose is?
[image]

There is some wire wrapped around the resistor and it's attached to the antenna.
[image]

This is the schematic for the tube radio.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

that is an air core transformer ... L2 in schematic ... one winding connects to an external antenna and the other winding connects to the internal loop antenna. .... the resistor is for mechanical support